# Set permissions for custom views

Tags: view, tableau-api

In Tableau Server, I have some statistics which can be filtered by-project with the default quick filter. I set each filter as a view.

I'd like different users to only be able to view projects relevant to them. How can I assign view permissions for different user groups? I can set views as public or not public but I don't see an option for individual permissions.

Comment: I think `view` level permission is set while `publishing` only . Data level access is different which is not your requirement here i guess.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Tableau Server are you on? In 9.2 they added a different way to edit the permissions of a project by a number of different ways.

[permissions window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Meiru.png)

Under the 'View' tab, you can set any combination of rules to dictate what users see and don't see.

You can also set permissions at the workbook level when you upload.
[Setting permissions in tableau](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/publish_workbooks_permissions_add.html)